# Replacing a plaintext user table with a view

Tags: php, drupal-views

We inherit things, some worse than others.

Recently inherited a user table that has plaintext passwords. Normally this isn't that big a deal but the table is connected to by many webapps -- Some of which I can't expect to find without them breaking and people complaining first.

I'd like to encrypt this password column without needing to modify the connection strings or hardcoded sql of these mystery apps. I was thinking it would be possible to authenticate TWO ways by replacing this table with a mysql view that uses an 'OR' clause. The idea would be something like encrypted_sql_check OR plaintext_sql_check, where plaintext sql check looks something like md5(plaintextpw, salt) or somesuch, essentially running the plaintext submission through a crypter with the salt used and checking for a match.

I'm not a dba though, so this is just a codemonkey spitballing some ideas. Is this feasable? Will I run into issues with insert/update/etc queries? In other words... Can someone tell me why this WON'T work? This database table will also serve as a drupal users table, so if there's any reason that would throw a kink into things it would also be good to know.

Thanks!

Comment: Someone on IRC just pointed out that the plaintext password will most likely be saved again to disk in a log file. Fail :/ Does anyone have any suggestions or thoughts in general about this whole idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view in a database is generally read-only, so yes, you will run into problems when trying to update or insert values through such a view. Working on the original table on the other hand should work and update the view immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Im aware of some of the issues with updating multitable views, but didn't think that would be a problem according to this doc. Maybe I'm wrong though? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/view-updatability.html

Comment: Going to just give up on this (IE, do it the normal way and rewrite all the apps) and give you the answer credit. Thanks for answering in any case!

Comment: Ah cool, didn't know that it was possible to update *some* views in MySQL, but on the other hand I am still convinced that views **shouldn't** be updatable and left as read-only query optimizers. I also doubt that there would be an easy way to _invert_ the view's function mechanism (using the salt + md5). As you've already stated it is indeed better to rewrite the apps to use a decent hashing mechanism to check passwords.